# how to create tabbar programmatically

Tags: iphone

HI all,
i am having navigation based application, in which i need too implement tab bars ,in one of view.
in one view i need 5 tabs, can any one please suggest me to create tab bars programmatically,, ? each tab should navigate to another xib.

Suggestions are always appreciated.
regards

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a sample code from Apple to create tab bar programmatically:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
   tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

   MyViewController* vc1 = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
   MyOtherViewController* vc2 = [[MyOtherViewController alloc] init];

   NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil];
   tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;

   // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
   [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}
```

[More here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW15)

Comment: @vodkhang...dat was perfect man..this is wat i was looking for.thanks a ton man

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that a tab bar controller implemented inside a navigation controller is unsupported by Apple. From the same doc linked to by vodhkang above:

> Note: Although a navigation controller can be embedded inside a tab, the reverse is not true. Presenting a tab bar interface from within a navigation interface is potentially confusing for users. A navigation interface uses one or more custom view controllers to present an interface focused on one goal, which is usually the management of a specific type of data. By contrast, the tabs of a tab bar interface can reflect completely different purposes in an application and need not be related in any way. In addition, pushing a tab bar controller on a navigation stack would cause the tabs to be displayed for that screen only and not for any others.

So instead of using UITabBarController consider implementing a tab bar with a UIViewController as the tab bar's delegate.