# How to set Tabbar integration in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, title, tabbar

I am working on an iPhone app, using UITabBar to develop it. Only the second tabbar title visible in tabbar, but first tabbar title not show in tabbar, how to fix this? please help me,
Thanks in Advance.

below is the source code for your reference.

```
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
tab =[[UITabBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, 320, 44)];

[self.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"sample1" image:nil tag:111];
[items addObject:self.tabBarItem];

[self.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"sample2" image:nil tag:101];
[items addObject:self.tabBarItem];

[tab setItems:items animated:YES]; 
[self.view addSubview:tab];
```

[image]

Comment: You'd better set a image for every tab.

Comment: i tried this to import image but warning comes, how to set system item image? [self.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"3" image:UITabBarSystemItemFeatured tag:11];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont navigate the view controllers, because then your controller which contains the TabBar will  get popped out.

When we use UITabBar we dont use navigation in this way.

Just addSubView the new controllers with such frame so that your TabBar will alwaz be visible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add that tabbarItem in UITabBar.

```
   NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    [items addObject:self.tabBarItem]; //add all your tabBarItems in an array
    [tab setItems:items animated:YES]; //then set all your tabBarItems in UITabBar like this
```

Comment: I tried this, but now tabbar background also not visible in the screen

Comment: Sorry it my fault, now  i tried this way 
 NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 tab =[[UITabBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, 320, 44)];
       
    [self.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"sample1" image:nil tag:11];
     [items addObject:self.tabBarItem];
    
    [self.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"sample2" image:nil tag:11];
     [items addObject:self.tabBarItem];
    [tab setItems:items animated:YES]; 
    [self.view addSubview:tab];

Comment: Only show second tab item in tabbar, the first tabbar item title not shown, please helep me

Comment: Hey Minu you are using same instance of tabbarItem alwaz thats'y at the end only one barItem is added.
Check Below I have added code in another answer , It will help you Out.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are using same instance of tabBarItem thats'y you are getting only second button.
Do this way, and Please if this helps you then accept the answer.

```
UITabBar *tabBar = [[UITabBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 725, 768, 49)];
    NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    UITabBarItem *item1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"first" image:nil tag:1];
    UITabBarItem *item2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"second" image:nil tag:2];
    UITabBarItem *item3 = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"third" image:nil tag:3];
    UITabBarItem *item4 = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"fourth" image:nil tag:4];

    [items addObject:item1];
    [items addObject:item2];
    [items addObject:item3];
    [items addObject:item4];

    [tabBar setItems:items];
    [self.view addSubview:tabBar];
```

Comment: and also i have one more question for this?

Comment: How to connect ViewController in all tabs, can u please help me

Comment: Minu Try this, it is a delegate method of UITabBar.

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{

}

Comment: I have already try this deepak.                                    - (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{

    NSLog(@"Tag:%d",item.tag);
    
    if(item.tag = 100)
    {
        Screen1 *s1 =[[screen1 alloc]init];
        [navi pushViewController:s1 animated:YES];
    }

} but when i press 1st screen it goes to screen1 but tabbar not visible on the screen, How to fix this? can u please geive simple example for this, i only hope you deepak

Comment: Actually this is perfect answer, should be an accepted answer. Current accepted answer has nothing to do with the question. Only perfect answer should be accepted here in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way you do to create and add a TabBar programmatically. 
You'd rather use this other method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3844365/655221

Good luck.

Comment: You are semi right @ale0xB.
The way you suggest is used when you are making your app totally TabBar based.
And above solution is only for if you want to add tab bar to some part of app only.
Thank You